# .NET Maui won't run application on iOS

Tags: ios, .net-maui

So I've got a simple app that works on the Android emulator and physical Opel phone, but when I deploy to iPhone I getting a bunch of errors. For starters...

```
Could not resolve assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract
```

Surely a tap gesture should work out of the box?

Here's the full list:

```
2022-08-22 23:14:34.473 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[94921:6409975] Could not resolve assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6B3B6CF6-2A5A-452F-956D-74D8A66941EA/Documents/Lofty.Logbook.content/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll' or one of its dependencies.

2022-08-22 23:14:34.475 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[94921:6409975] Could not resolve assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6B3B6CF6-2A5A-452F-956D-74D8A66941EA/Documents/Lofty.Logbook.content/Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll' or one of its dependencies.

Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointSendToIde(System.String)' to D:\a\_work\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:419 [0x00000].
2022-08-22 23:14:34.617 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[94921:6409975] Could not resolve assembly Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6B3B6CF6-2A5A-452F-956D-74D8A66941EA/Documents/Lofty.Logbook.content/Xamarin.HotReload.Contracts.dll' or one of its dependencies.

2022-08-22 23:14:34.618 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[94921:6409975] Could not resolve assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6B3B6CF6-2A5A-452F-956D-74D8A66941EA/Documents/Lofty.Logbook.content/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.dll' or one of its dependencies.

Resolved pending breakpoint for 'Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.BreakpointCheckpoint()' to D:\a\_work\1\s\HotReload\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:414 [0x00000].
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'MauiProgram.cs:40,1' to Lofty.Logbook.Database.EntityDbContext Lofty.Logbook.MauiProgram.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<CreateMauiApp>b__1 (System.IServiceProvider x) [0x00058].
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'MauiProgram.cs:32,1' to Lofty.Logbook.Database.EntityDbContext Lofty.Logbook.MauiProgram.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<CreateMauiApp>b__1 (System.IServiceProvider x) [0x00023].
Thread started:  #7
Thread started:  #8
Thread started:  #9
2022-08-22 23:14:35.102 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[94921:6409975] Could not resolve assembly System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=en-AU, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6B3B6CF6-2A5A-452F-956D-74D8A66941EA/Documents/Lofty.Logbook.content/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.

2022-08-22 23:14:35.103 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[94921:6409975] Could not resolve assembly System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6B3B6CF6-2A5A-452F-956D-74D8A66941EA/Documents/Lofty.Logbook.content/System.Private.DataContractSerialization.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.

2022-08-22 23:14:35.247 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[94921:6409975] Could not resolve assembly Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.resources, Version=6.0.8.0, Culture=en-AU, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6B3B6CF6-2A5A-452F-956D-74D8A66941EA/Documents/Lofty.Logbook.content/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.

2022-08-22 23:14:35.248 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[94921:6409975] Could not resolve assembly Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.resources, Version=6.0.8.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6B3B6CF6-2A5A-452F-956D-74D8A66941EA/Documents/Lofty.Logbook.content/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.

    [0:] An error occurred: 'e_sqlite3'. Callstack: '   at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3.SQLitePCL.ISQLite3Provider.sqlite3_libversion_number()
       at SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(ISQLite3Provider imp)
       at SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init()
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)'
    The app has been terminated.
```

Anyone know how to resolve this? I'm guessing sqlite pcl is the main issue

**Update**: Here's a demo project that illustrates the issue I'm facing. https://github.com/steveski/MauiEFIssue

Comment: Have you created the `Entitlements.plist` file and pasted it under Platforms/iOS folder in your MAUI project? If not, see my answer.

Comment: I see those "could not resolve assembly" errors all the time and they don't impact my app. The Entitlements.plist is not a requirement to successful execution. The exception seems to imply an issues with SQLite. Have you tried to pinpoint which line of EF code causes the issue?

Comment: Has nothing to do with SQL Lite. I'm getting the same error and not touching anything related to SQL. Didn't start seeing these errors until started including the MSAL libraries.

Comment: @TomasMcGuinness After the creation of the EntityDbContext is where it dies, somewhere in the lifecycle hooks of the base DbContext. It never gets past the new EntityDbContext call

Comment: I dont know why, but removing all breakpoints solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

You need add a new `entitlements` file to your `.NET Multi-platform App UI` (.NET MAUI) app project, and add a new XML file named **Entitlements.plist** to the `Platforms\iOS\` folder of your app project. Then add the following XML to the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Update**: I found a working example, you can refer to [it](https://github.com/VladislavAntonyuk/MauiSamples/tree/main/Sqlite).

Comment: Is the dictionary supposed to remain empty? I added the file but get the same errors

Comment: Yes, you can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/entitlements#add-an-entitlementsplist-file) and you can also copy the `Entitlements.plist` file from your working Xamarin.Forms iOS app. BTW, how do you configure the `sqlite pcl` in your MAUI project? Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo?

Comment: I'll put together a reproducible example, but the app works fine in the android emulator and on android. The system does work, just something about iOS. Will get an example going

Comment: I created a new project and modified nothing at all and it deployed to the iPhone and runs fine. So that eliminates Entitlements being a requirement for deployment.

Comment: Then the issue should be related with the `sqlite pcl` in your MAUI project.

Comment: It's strange, my demo minimal demo I put together wasn't working, but as soon as I put the entitlements.plist in with an empyu <dict> element it worked... grizzle. Can't explain why it's not in my main project. But then now I can't run my main project anymore ....

Comment: ... getting this now. ```Deploy Error: Could not install the application 'C:\Users\.........\Logbook.ipa' on the device You Bute Communications Device. Details: MismatchedApplicationIdentifierEntitlement - Upgrade's application-identifier entitlement string (K4Rxxxxxx.com.myorg.logbook) does not match installed application's application-identifier string (53Bxxxxxx.com.myorg.logbook); rejecting upgrade.```. I'm seriously getting worn down over all the issues that can randomly occur with this platform. It's why I gave up on Xamarin years ago. Trying to not let go this time.

Comment: I've edited the original post to include the reproduceable example.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how the working example is equivalent to the issue I'm having. The errors I showed in my post  clearly show that EntityFrameworkCore is unable to load. That example you added doesn't use EF. Have you looked at my reproduceable example?

Comment: I'm sorry that using `EntityFrameworkCore` is beyond my scope.

Comment: Is there anyone within Microsoft for whom it is in scope?

Comment: I found a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72598734/entity-framework-core-in-net-maui-xamarin-forms) that may be helpful. If it still doesn't work, you can also ask a question in [this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/index.html).

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT - Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When first testing my cross-platform MAUI app (for Android and iOS), my app would not run on iOS deployed from Visual Studio 2022 (Windows 11) to a remote iPhone connected to my MacBookPro running Ventura/XCode 15.2.  The solution for me was to configure Manual Provisioning with AdHoc Distribution profile.  The app would appear to install correctly but would not run with Automatic provisioning.  Manual provisioning is configured in Properties > iOS > Bundle Signing.