# .NET MAUI FileProvider on Android does not work in release mode

Tags: .net-6.0, maui, android-fileprovider

I am attempting to install an apk file using .NET MAUI on an Android device like so:

```
var bytes = DownloadApkFile();
var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.CacheDirectory, "app.apk");
File.WriteAllBytes(file, bytes);

var context = Android.App.Application.Context; 
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);
using (Android.Content.Intent install = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionView))
{
     var uri = Microsoft.Maui.Storage.FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".fileProvider", file);
     install.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
     install.AddFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.NewTask);
     install.AddFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
     install.AddFlags(Android.Content.ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
     install.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraNotUnknownSource, true);
     Platform.CurrentActivity.StartActivity(install);
}
```

**This works perfectly in debug mode**, but in release mode I get the following exception: `Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.mycompany.mobile.fileProvider`

I thought maybe I needed to add a `[ContentProvider]` attribute to the application, but then it no longer builds because of duplicate content providers for `androidx.core.content.FileProvider`, so I assume MAUI is including this content provider automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android/iOS linkers are removing chunks of the assemblies of your app due to the heavy use of reflection. You can verify this by adding code as follows in the `csproj` file as follows :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And you can also instruct the linker to keep some of the important assemblies .

The steps are as follows: :

1. Add an XML file named `Linker.xml` to your Android project.
2. Right click `Linker.xml` in your Solution Explorer then select Properties.
3. Change Build Action to `LinkDescription`.

There is a simimar thread,you can check it here  [Linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72598734/entity-framework-core-in-net-maui-xamarin-forms).

Comment: Setting the linker to `None` resolved the issue, but I also had to disable `RunAOTCompilation` and `AndroidEnableProfiledAot` or my application crashed on startup.
I haven't tried the custom Linker.xml file as I don't really know how to determine *what* to whitelist.